# How to expand a non value paramter pack

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I've been trying to expand a non value parameter pack recently in C++. Is this possible? And if it's not, why?

I mean, as you can see, in the line with the comment `//`, given a parameter pack for the `TypeMap` class, how can I call `addType<T>()` with each type of the parameter pack? Thanks in advance!

```
template <typename... T>
class TypeMap
{
    using vari_cmps = std::variant<T*...>;

    private:
        template<typename Type>
        void addType()
        {
            typemap[typeid(Type).name()] = std::make_unique<Type>(0).get();
        }

    public:
        std::map<const char*, vari_cmps> typemap{};

        TypeMap()
        {
            (addType<T,...>()); // Idk how to use this in order to make it work
        }

        ~TypeMap()
        {
            typemap.clear();
        }
};
```

Comment: `(addType<T>(), ...);`. Also remove the destructor (you don't need it, and it prevents your class from being moved, forcing it to always be copied).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat you are [as fast as Chuck Norris](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts) with your answers :-) As for the redundant destructor, I've just posted [a blog post](https://blog.devgenius.io/10-mistakes-to-avoid-when-using-std-vector-274043ca157c) listing potential issues using `vector` with a similar mistake - see item #9 there. I got a feedback from someone that this is a rare problem, I argued that I do see it occasionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @HolyBlackCat has already answered in the comments, you can expand it like this:

```cpp
TypeMap() {
    (addType<T>(), ...);
}
```

If T is `std::string, int, float` this would expand to:

```cpp
TypeMap() {
    (addType<std::string>(), addType<int>(), addType<float>());
}
```

---

There are however a few more issues in this code-snippet:

##### 1. addType()

`addType()` will not work as you'd expect, due to the unique_ptr deleteing your object after you put it into the map.

`.get()` only retrieves the pointer that the `unique_ptr` manages but does **not** transfer ownership, so the unique_ptr will still delete the pointed-to object once it gets out of scope, leaving a dangling pointer in your map.

so your `addType()` is roughly equivalent to:

```cpp
template<typename Type>
void addType() {
    Type* tptr = new Type(0); // unique pointer constructs object
    typemap[typeid(Type).name()] = tptr; // insert pointer value of unique pointer
    delete tptr; // unique pointer destructs
}
```

You could fix this by releasing the unique_ptr after inserting its value into the map & then cleaning it up in the destructor:

```cpp
template<typename Type>
void addType() {
    auto ptr = std::make_unique<Type>(0);
    typemap[typeid(Type).name()] = ptr.get();
    ptr.release(); // now unique_ptr won't delete the object
}

~TypeMap() {
    // cleanup all pointers
    for(auto& [name, ptrVariant] : typemap)
        std::visit([](auto ptr) { delete ptr; }, ptrVariant);
}
```

##### 2. Consider using `std::type_index` instead of `const char*` as map key

`std::type_info::name()` returns an implementation-defined name for the given type, so you have no guarantee that you will get an unique name for a given type.

> Returns an implementation defined null-terminated character string containing the name of the type. No guarantees are given; in particular, the returned string can be identical for several types and change between invocations of the same program.

`std::type_index` on the other hand is build specifically for this purpose - using types as keys - and comes with all comparison operators & a `std::hash` specialization, so you can use it with `std::map` & `std::unordered_map` out of the box.

e.g.:

```
template <class... T>
class TypeMap
{
    using vari_cmps = std::variant<T*...>;

    private:
        template<typename Type>
        void addType()
        {
            typemap[std::type_index(typeid(Type))] = /* something */;
        }

    public:
        std::map<std::type_index, vari_cmps> typemap{};

        TypeMap() { /* ... */ }
        ~TypeMap() { /* ... */ }

        template<class U>
        U* get() {
            auto it = typemap.find(std::type_index(typeid(U)));
            return std::get<U*>(it->second);
        }
};
```

---

##### Consider using `std::tuple`

[std::tuple](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) is basically built for this task, storing a list of arbitrary types:

e.g.:

```cpp
template <class... T>
class TypeMap
{
private:
    std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<T>...> values;
public:
    TypeMap() : values(std::make_unique<T>(0)...) {
    }

    template<class U> requires (std::is_same_v<U, T> || ...)
    U& get() { return *std::get<std::unique_ptr<U>>(values); }

    template<class U> requires (std::is_same_v<U, T> || ...)
    U const& get() const { return *std::get<std::unique_ptr<U>>(values); }
};
```

usage:

```cpp
TypeMap<int, double, float> tm;
tm.get<int>() = 12;
```

If you want you can also store `T`'s directly in the tuple, avoiding the additional allocations.